# What is the phrase for "the speed that country injects the vaccine"?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to use one phrase to talk about "the speed that country injects the vaccine". Is there any suitable phrase for this need? I am thinking of "vaccination progress" but it seems not that really smooth. Another word is "[vaccine injection speed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27527817/)" is relating to the speed that the nurse inject the medicine to our body.

Comment: Rate of vaccination?

Comment: Or "roll-out of the vaccination programme"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Can I ask what  does  "roll-out" mean in this case?

Comment: @NoviceMindset "the launch or introduction of  a product or service." i.e. the organisation of the vaccination programme.